# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word SpellingChecked not returning true value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get Spellingchecked to tell me if a word document has spellingchecked on or not, however it returns false regardless of what I do, I even tried changing it to true and console logging after that and it still comes back false. Can anyone help? Here is the block of code I'm stuck on:

```
document = word.ActiveDocument;
Boolean SpellingChecked = document.SpellingChecked;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("Spelling check is set to " + (SpellingChecked ? "true" : "false"));
                Console.WriteLine(fileName);
                if (SpellingChecked == false)
                {
                    document.SpellingChecked = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Spelling check has now been changed to " + (SpellingChecked ? "true" : "false"));
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the `SpellingChecked` boolean variable and the document's `SpellingChecked` property.

By doing `document.SpellingChecked = true;` you successfully set the document's spellchecking to `true`, but the `SpellingChecked` variable has not been altered, and thus will keep the `false` value.

In any case, you can skip using a boolean variable for this:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Spelling check is set to " + document.SpellingChecked);
Console.WriteLine(fileName);
if (!document.SpellingChecked)
{
    document.SpellingChecked = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Spelling check has now been changed to " + document.SpellingChecked);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Innat3 that has helped me progress. However when I run it, it shows SpellChecked set to false, then it changes to true which is great but, when i try to run it again it starts off false again.. so it doesn't appear to be changing? Is this something you can answer or does it need a new question?

Comment: @Nethalin I noticed that as well, the thing is, it shows as false even if it's enabled. I think a better question would be "Why do you need to set it to true? What do you intend to accomplish by turning on spellchecking through C#?"

Comment: I'm trying to create it where it checks through word documents, and if it detects spellcheck is off then console log that it was switched off and turn spellcheck on. That's all i wanted to do with it.

Comment: @Nethalin like I said, the SpellingChecked property is not reliable, it returns the value `false` even if spellchecking is enabled.

Comment: do you know any alternatives I could use?